# Problems installing package email in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, email

I am using Windows 10.
I just tried in my Anaconda prompt: pip install email
I got the following error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DIMITR~1.LIA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1vvnmrhi\email\email\parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cStringIO import StringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no need to install email via pip. Just import it in your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you do not have the package `cStringIO`.

To resolve this use following:

```
pip install cStringIO
```

if this does not help, try:

```
pip install StringIO
```

Here is more documentation about the packages `StringIO` and `cStringIO` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html